Does anyone have any suggestions on how to identify changes in streamflow response to precipitation events after a disturbance?
I have a .csv file containing data for stream discharge, stream flashiness, and precipitation over 15 minute intervals from 2010 until 2022. The format of my .csv file is
Date, Time, Discharge, Flashiness, Precipitation
2010-05-01, 0:00:00, 0.299, 0.0, 0.0
2010-05-01, 0:15:00, 0.319, 0.020, 4.6
2010-05-01, 0:30:00, 0.371, 0.052, 3.1
In the .csv file mentioned above, "Date" is the date ranging from 2010-05-01 to 2022-10-31, "Time" is the time of day (measured in 15-minute intervals), "Discharge" is the discharge measurement from the hydrometric streamflow gauge at each time interval, "Flashiness" is the 15-minute increase in stream discharge at each time interval (compared to the discharge at the previous time interval), and "Precipitation" is the precipitation depth that has fallen over each 15-minute time interval.
Incremental disturbances have been added to the watershed (2013, 2016, and 2019), and I want to be able to test whether (and the extent to which) these disturbances change the "Flashiness" in response to the "Precipitation". i.e., is the relationship between precipitation depth and the corresponding increase in stream discharge statistically different before 2013, between 2013 and 2016, and after 2019? Does anyone have any advice on how to approach this?
I want to be able to create a model and see if the 15-minute interval flashiness response to precipitation is statistically different over the four time periods (i.e., the time period before the first disturbance (i.e., 2010 to 2012), the time period between the first and second disturbance (i.e., 2014 to 2016), the time period between the second and third disturbance (i.e., 2017 to 2019), and the time period between the forth disturbance and the end of 2022 (i.e., 2020 to 2022)). Each of these four time periods (i.e., 2010 to 2012, 2014 to 2016, 2017 to 2019, and 2020 to 2022) have an equal sample size (i.e., three years of data taken over a 15-minute interval).
I am unsure how or what tests could be used to determine if stream flashiness in response to precipitation is statistically different between time periods. I would appreciate any feedback or suggestions that anyone may have as I have no idea what I am doing at this point. TIA
I first tried using Generalized Additive Models (GAMs) to model the relationship between the daily precipitation depth (mm) and the daily increase in stream discharge (i.e., flashiness) both before the first disturbance (i.e., 2010 to 2012) and after (i.e., 2020 to 2022) the last disturbance. However, as these models use daily data rather than sub-daily data, I was unable to account for rainfall intensity and timing. As rainfall intensity and timing inevitably influences the increase in stream discharge (i.e., flashiness), I was not getting a very good fit to my model without accounting for these factors. Does anyone know of any statistical tests that can account for time?
I also used a time series analysis and ARIMA models to look at increasing or decreasing trends in the precipitation and discharge over time. However, ARIMA models are univariate and use only the previous values in the time series to predict future values. As such, ARIMA models could not be used to understand the relationship between the precipitation and discharge time series.

I have performed such studies.  Even a sketch of a set of answers to all your questions would take too much time and space here; but I only wish to redirect your efforts away from formal tests and towards exploration.  Such data are really, really messy and benefit from careful examination and processing.  If you ultimately need formal verification of hypotheses, you can still accomplish that by either holding out a long, contiguous subset of data or by performing your exploration on a similar dataset for another stream or reach of this stream.

Thank you. Unfortunately, this is part of my Ph.D. and requires a formal verification of hypotheses to defend. I found another study where they compared two neighboring streams. I thought I would do something similar, but, there are no other streams of similar size in the area to compare to. I was hoping to use precipitation as a predictor variable for stream discharge and compare the extent to which precipitation depth and intensity influences magnitude of stream discharge, and whether this relationship changes over the three time periods (i.e., 2010 to 2012, 2013 to 2019, and 2020 to 2022).
